# Update Assembly Version only if project have changed

Tags: tfs

I am configuring a Team Foundation Server build and i succeed to update the last number for every check in in the server.
Now i want to do 2 things:

- first, if the solution contains several projects, i want to update
  only project who have changed. I wanted to work with the modified date of assemblyinfo but i didn't succeeded.
- second for each solution in my TFS, i want an independant gestion of incremental version like this

  TFS
  -Solution A

  --Project A

  -Solution B

  --Project A

If i check in on project A from solution A, the assembly version should be 1.0.0.1.

If i check in on project A from solution B, the assembly version should be 1.0.0.1.(Currently, i got 1.0.0.2)

I used several links for implement incremental versionning like this link => http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx
But after a long search, i didn't get a good link for what i want to do.
Thanks to help me :)

Regards,
Matthieu

Comment: You should upgrade to TFS 2013. Things are a lot Easter.

Comment: yeah maybe but i am not THE BOSS :) but we are going to upgrade to TFS 2013 next year.

Comment: TFS 2015 will be out next year so hopefully you will be upgrading to that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a series of posts on this topic, starting at http://blog.casavian.eu/blog/2014/04/23/increment-version-for-changed-assemblies-only-first-part/. You should find answers to all your questions, if not let me know.

Comment: It's fine to promote your blog post like that, but you also need to include (excerpt) some of the material here in your answer. As it stands your answer is little more than a link to an offsite resource - this sort of answer is discouraged.

Comment: I understand this, but is will be a pages-long answer. There are many pieces and moving parts, hard to summarize.
It is not self-promotion: I worked on this topic, find some solutions, which requires understanding of context.

Comment: Still, give it a go - otherwise it will be matter of time before your answer gets flagged, ends up on the review queue, and ultimately gets deleted due to its brevity. Good answers take time to create, but they get lots of visits and regular up votes.